# Proving $\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}(-1)^k{n-m\choose k}\frac{k}{k+m}=-{n\choose m}^{-1}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

So apparently we can calculate the value of this series as
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}(-1)^k{n-m\choose k}\frac{k}{k+m}=-\frac{m!(n-m)!}{n!}=-{n\choose m}^{-1}$$
But I'm curious to prove this holds.

So I thought maybe I can do it by induction on $k$ and write it in terms of the Gamma function but I was not successful.

Could anyone give me a hint please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's clean up stuff a bit; let $n=m+\ell$. Then, the required sum $S$ is
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}(-1)^k\binom{\ell}{k}\dfrac{k}{m+k}$$
$$=\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}(-1)^k\binom{\ell}{k}}_{=(1-1)^{\ell}=0}-\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}\dfrac{(-1)^km}{m+k}\binom{\ell}{k}$$
Now, we consider the function
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}\binom{\ell}{k}\dfrac{x^{k+m}}{k+m}$$
From here, we have $S=-mf(-1)/(-1)^m$. Now, differentiating the above equation,
$$f'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\ell}\binom{\ell}{k}x^{k+m-1}=x^{m-1}(1+x)^{\ell}$$
I hope you can take it from here.